# Adding a KML layer to an Android maps application

Tags: android, google-maps, android-mapview, kml

I have been starting out in the world of Android development recently and I am working on an application which shows a map using the Google API SDK, it is pretty much the original example but edited a little bit. It works a treat but I wish to do more with it. My question is:

How do you add a KML layer to this? I've not found many examples out there and none of them are very clear. I know how to do this with Javascript on websites but not in android.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 5):

Google added a support to KML recently in its utility lib. You can instantiate a KMLLayer as below:

```
KmlLayer layer = new KmlLayer(getMap(), R.raw.kmlFile, getApplicationContext());
```

Or if you have a stream (maybe the kml you need is on a remote server):

```
KmlLayer layer = new KmlLayer(getMap(), kmlInputStream, getApplicationContext());
```

After this you have to add the layer to the map:

```
layer.addLayerToMap();
```

More info on [Google Maps KML Importing Utility](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/utility/kml).
The library is here: [Google Maps Android API utility library](http://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/) (you need 0.4+ version)

CAUTION: At the time, it's a Beta feature. In fact it seems you can't make any modifications to polygons, changing their styles, and so on...

I hope it helped.

Comment: Are you using 0.4+ version?

Comment: I forgot to add a compile "clause" on app gradle build file (`compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4+'`). Now, it as all right. Thx

Comment: Can you please approve my answer?

Comment: I did it before yesterday

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't notice you weren't the owner of the question. I was talking to Nick Lewis.

Comment: But, what about KMZ files? I cannot open them with the same KmlLayer and I'm going crazy :)

Comment: Looks like this is STILL in beta -___-. I will probably need to preprocess KMLs as polylines in order to massage them at run time.

Comment: @andrea.rinaldi, the way I got the kmz to load into google maps is by changing the file name from "name.kmz" to "name.zip" and then extract it using "zipinputstream" and then taking path of the extracted file which is a "kml" file... use "FileInputStream" to that "kml" file to load it as KMLLayer... we can load "R.raw" file and aswell as local storage file using fileinputstream

Answer (score 2):

If you are ready to move to OpenSteetMap maps, then you can use [osmdroid](https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid) and [OSMBonusPack](https://github.com/MKergall/osmbonuspack) to have KML support for: reading, saving, displaying and styling.

There is a [dedicated tutorial](https://github.com/MKergall/osmbonuspack/wiki/Tutorial_4) about KML.