# open a google map with local database in my android application

Tags: android, android-maps

i am creating an application in which i need to open the google map to show some nearby locations, the addresses are stored in my local DB.
can anybody suggest me what is the best way, or it will be very helpful if u share some demo code.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to marshall your DB contents into a kml file and have the map view show that. This guy shows how to to do it in a previous post [Adding a KML layer to an Android maps application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4096142/adding-a-kml-layer-to-an-android-maps-application/4416854#4416854)